# Delphi 10.1, function que só aceite um intervalo de integer na variavel

Tags: delphi, funções, declaração-de-variável

Parece algo fácil, mas não estou conseguindo. Quero poder definir um tipo de variável ao criar uma function ou procedure, mas que só aceite números inteiros entre 1 e 4 por exemplo durante a chamada da function/procedure. Números estes que já possam ser usados nela.

algo como:

```
function Algo(TAlgo: array [1...4] of integer);
```

onde nem aceite compilar caso eu chame:

Algo(5);//retornar erro, nem aceite compilar
Algo(1);//ok
Algo(2);//ok
Algo(3);//ok
Algo(4);//ok

Consegui aproximar, mas estou tentando simplificar o código abaixo, conforme exemplo acima. Até agora eu consegui algo parecido, criando um *Type*, conforme abaixo:

Criei um *Type*:

```
    TQtd = (xUma, xDuas, xTres, xQuatro);
```

E dentro da function, uma var e um case:

```
var
  iQtd:Integer;
...
  case Precision of
    xUma: iQtd := 1;
    xDuas: iQtd := 2;
    xTres: iQtd := 3;
    xQuatro: iQtd := 4;
  end;
```

Assim, uso a variável iQtd e obtenho o que preciso, chamando a function desta forma:

```
functionTal(xTres);
```

Há como eu criar, já especificando que é integer, aceitando apenas de 1 a 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possível criar uma type utilizando um range de integer, ex:

```
Type
  TAteQuatro = 1..4;

  procedure Teste(valor: TAteQuatro);
  begin
    Writeln(valor);
  end;
begin
  Teste(4); //Compila
  Teste(5); //[dcc32 Error] Rangezera.dpr(20): E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds
end.
```